# PHP OOP: Function not return all row in database to php

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a function that suppose to return all row in database to browser, but it is return only one value. Below is my table:

[image]

And this is my code:

SqlDatabase.php Classes:

```
public function query($sql){

        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);

        return $result;
    }
```

test.php:

```
$database = new SqlDatabase;
//testing function
    public static function find_comments($photo_id=0){
        global $database;
        $sql  = "select * from comments";
        $sql .= " where photograph_id = {$photo_id}";
        $sql .= " order by created ASC";
        print_r(self::sql_find($sql));
    }
    // This is a testing function
    public static function sql_find($sql){
        global $database;
        $result_set = $database->query($sql);
        $object_array = array();
        while ($row = $database->fetch_assoc($result_set)){
            $object_array = $row['author'];
        } return $object_array;
    }
```

When i try to run this function, It is only return one last value "vai het loc" to PHP:

```
Comments::find_comments(77);
```

I tried several ways and do researchs but haven't found any solutions yet. Not sure what am i missing. Need some guide to fetch all row in photograph_id not only one value.

Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're overwriting the value, not appending it to the array.

Change this line:

```
$object_array = $row['author'];
```

to this:

```
$object_array[] = $row['author'];
```

In your `sql_find()` function and you should get the object.

Comment: Yepp, thats works. I forgot to put [] in $object_array :) Thank you Darren :-)